# How get name of remote computer location

Tags: powershell, computer-name

How would I use powerShell to find the name of a remote computer/NAS location?  I don't have the name, just a path to get there in Windows Explorer.  I'm trying to use the following command in a script, but don't have computername for the NAS at network location \usa0xxxnas1.na.xxx.net\directory1:

```
invoke-command -computername <UnknownNameGoesHere> -credential $globalcred -scriptblock{test-path...}
```

I've been looking at this link but it's not answering my question, since they need the computerName (london) to run the command they are discussing, unless I'm mis-understanding something:
[name of remote computer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/25159bb0-9be8-4ef3-8c23-d087aec61d09/get-remote-computer-name)

Comment: `-ComputerName` parameter doesn't have to be actual (NetBIOS) name. It can be IP address or anything that resolves to IP address. In you case it seems to be `usa0xxxnas1.na.xxx.net`.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht You should post that as an answer.